# Entity Framework 4 + stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

Hope you guys can help me.

This is my situation.

I have a stored procedure that returns a very dynamic `#table` (the number of columns are not fixed)

It accepts 4 parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE cct_AbsHoursPossible
    @_TpCode VarChar(9),
    @_Period VarChar(20),
    @_StartDate DateTime,
    @_EndDate DateTime
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET FMTONLY OFF
```

I include the stored procedure in my model, and I added the function import and created the complex type.

BUT when I call the stored procedure with the following code

```
ctx.cct_AbsHoursPossible("V109   03", "A%", _start, _end);
```

It gives me the following error.

> *Procedure or function 'cct_AbsHoursPossible' expects parameter
>   '@_TpCode', which was not supplied.*

I have searched the web and could not come up with any solutions.

I am pretty new to .net development..

Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you use an nvarchar instead of a varchar?

Comment: Yes, Exactly the same problem.

Comment: And if you remove _ from the beginning of the parameter names? Look at the definition for the cct_AbsHoursPossible method and check the parameter names match.

Comment: Having the stored procedure return different result sets (different shapes, e.g. number and types of columns) makes it next to **impossible** to use this from Entity Framework. Also, I'd say such a stored procedure is a bad design - it makes it very hard in any case to deal with that procedure - don't do that!

Comment: THANKS!!, that sorts at least my Parameter error out, FINALLY.

Comment: @marc_s unfortunally in the perfect world your statement would make perfect sense but in my world I NEED to write a SP that returns a dynamic result set. If I had any other way of doing it I would have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the underscores from the beginning of your parameter names.